# Can I set up a way to load iTerm with or without Full Disk Access on the fly?

Tags: catalina, iterm, privacy

I really appreciate Catalina's "Full Disk Access" Privacy right for keeping software I run in iTerm out of things like removable volumes, photos, etc.

However, sometimes I *do* need to use iTerm in some of these folders, especially when maintaining Time Machine drives, etc.

Is it possible to create an alternate way of launching iTerm that selectively has Full Disk Access?

I tried:

- copying iTerm and pasting a new copy, renaming it "iTerm (Full Disk Access)"
- unzipping a new copy of iTerm and renaming it "iTerm (Full Disk Access)"

but neither asked for new rights—they both inherited the rights of the main iTerm application.

Comment: I don't think there is. I believe the permission is tied to the App's Bundle ID (com.googlecode.iterm2) which doesn't change, regardless of where you put it. Obviously you could give Terminal.app FDA and leave iTerm without FDA… but then you'd have to use Terminal ;-)

Comment: @TJLuoma Amusingly enough, this is my current "solution", heh.